# Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService::createSlug(): Argument #3 ($fromString) must be of type string, null

Tags: php, html, laravel

I get the error message when I try to create unique slug with sluggable, in vsCode nothing error, and it's fine, but when I open in web server I get the error message. And this is the error message

```
Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Services\SlugService::createSlug(): Argument #3 ($fromString) must be of type string, 
null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\foresell\app\Http\Controllers\DataProdukController.php on line 240
```

**this my controller**

```
    public function checkSlug(Request $request)
    {
        $slug = SlugService::createSlug(Produk::class, 'slug', $request->name);

        return response()->json(['slug' => $slug]);
    }
}
```

**this is my model**

```
public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

**this is my view**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
    @error('name')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror


    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Slug Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" class="form-control">
    </div>
    @error('slug')
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
<script>

    const name = document.querySelector("#name");
    const slug = document.querySelector("#slug");

    name.addEventListener('change', () => {
        fetch('/admin_toko/data_produk/create?name' + name.value)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => slug.value = data.slug );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: did you try checking the `$request->name` in your controller if empty?

Comment: yes, I check `dd($request->name);` still null

Answer (score 0):

If you check in this [package code](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable/blob/master/src/Services/SlugService.php#L408)

`public static function createSlug($model, string $attribute, string $fromString, array $config = null): string`

it say's that your 3rd parameter is `null`, but the function `createSlug` It only accept string in its 3rd parameter.

You need to check first the
`$request->name` if empty in your controller

`$slug = SlugService::createSlug(Produk::class, 'slug', $request->name);`

if `null` make sure to handle it

like for example:

```
public function checkSlug(Request $request) 
{ 
  $slug = "";
  if(!empty($request->name)) {
    $slug = SlugService::createSlug(Produk::class, 'slug' , $request->name);
  }
  return response()->json(['slug' => $slug]);
}
```

Comment: yeah no error, but in web server still return json not in view